# Multiple account types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently work on a site that must have several types of accounts

- Student
- Business

But companies will have different attributes, or more attributes.

How would I handle this with Identity?

Comment: What does "account type" mean? What does it matter for your application? If you want permissions based on the "type", then the idiomatic way is to assign roles and to authorize actions against these roles. If you want to store extra data depending on the account type, you can use different columns or tables to store this data.

Comment: Yes but if I do like this, a student push a Siren attribute is quite dirty ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use these different types as an ***Identity data***, so you can inherit default `IdentityUser` class in your types. You can also use `Claims` or implement your own `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` interfaces and use your magical logic to determine type of user.

One of the best (and the simplest) ways is to use roles and claims. Based on user role(s) you can determine what content is accessible to current user and what is not and also prevent access to controller methods from browser request (just typing url)